# How to use a `lr_scheduler` when you don't known how many training steps to do?

Tags: bert, transformer, learning-rate

I am trying to fine-tune a BERT model, but instead of doing it a fix number of training step, I want to use a stalling policy and allow it to run until the model stalls for N evaluations. However, I was previously using the `transformers.get_linear_schedule_with_warmup`, which requires an explicit number of training steps.

Is there any other learning rate scheduler that I should use for this task?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which framework to write out. But pytorch has [torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau.html). This scheduler allows you to reduce the learning rate if the quality metric on the validation data has not changed for the better for more than n epochs (there are also other useful settings).